# AlarmManger malfunctioning in android ?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have to call a service in every day on a particular time.obviously i had choose `AlarmManager` for waking up my service.and all working well other than `AlarmManager` triggering immediately when i set the past time.but it's working fine when i set time after current time.

For better clarification i will say an example.

> WORKING ATTEMPT : Current time is `09.00 AM` am setting schedule as
>   `10.00 AM`.And `AlarmManager` doing his job perfectly.
>
> FAILURE ATTEMPT :Current time is `10.00 AM` am setting schedule as
>   `09.00 AM`.And `AlarmManager` calls the services immediately.

***Actually i need to invoke my service tomorrow `09.00 AM` as the scheduled time is past.***

I referred some query almost matching this one but it wasn't good enough.What i am doing wrong ?

> **My Code**

```
       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10); 
       calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
       calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

       Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
       myIntent.putExtra(ACTION, ACTION_SC_1);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE_SC_1, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use alarm manager use [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager) which was introduced in the last IO. It will work like a charm and you will have the ability to set in to *inexact* alarm so u wont need to wakeup the device. From the google IO site : Google Play Services has added the GCM Network Manager which functions mostly like JobScheduler, but extends to prior releases before Lollipop.

Comment: Why do u need to use the old api? there are a lot of blogs/lectures of google that say dont use it because u will burn uneccessary battery.

Comment: I don't hve any huge network operation in my service.and i don't want to import google play service for this small operation.please tell me if you know the answer for my query :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Like set(int, long, PendingIntent), except you can also supply a period at which the alarm will automatically repeat. This alarm continues repeating until explicitly removed with cancel(PendingIntent). **If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately**, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.

It is working intentionally like this.

Answer (score 0):

As Bonatti said above, this is documented behaviour of the API when you set a time in the past.

You will need logic in your app to push out the alarm by 24hrs if it is already past 10am at the time when you want to set the alarm.

The easiest way to do this is probably to use the Calendar object as you have, then query

```
if (calendar.after(SystemClock.currentTimeMillis()) {
    // Push alarm out til tomorrow.
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the alarm to be triggered at 9AM sharp, don't use setRepeating() as it will not launch at the exact time since Android KitKat (this is also documented, you should really read the docs).

Use Calendar to build the timestamp from your desired alarm time. Check if the result timestamp is smaller than the current timestamp System.currentTimeMillis(), in that case it's in the past so add 24 hours to it to schedule it for the next day.
Finally, use AlarmManager.set() on older versions or AlarmManager.setExact() on newer versions of Android to schedule your alarm. Once the alarm goes off, you can schedule the next one using the same technique.